# Matrix Equation Text over text in braces

Tags: math-mode, equations, matrices, braces, text-decorations

[image]

Hi, how can I write this equation in Latex?

Comment: And why not simply write it like this: `[X]_{M\times N} = [U]_{M\times M}[S]_{M\times N}[V]_{N\times N}`?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Could you explain the notation of `M` and `N` in the (vertical) middle? What's the difference between that and the superscript `T`?

Comment: @Werner I guess the `T` stands for transposed. The formula looks a bit like a Smith normal form.

Comment: @AboAmmar: I agree. Perhaps [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzWi2.png).

Answer (score 1):

Never seen this kind of formula, so I don't know if this exactly what you want to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mymatr}[2]{\big[\overset{\scriptscriptstyle #1}{#2}\big]}
\newcommand{\myind}[1]{\raisebox{1pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle #1$}}
\begin{document}
    \[
    \mymatr{N}{X}\myind{M}=
        \myind{M}\mymatr{M}{U}\mymatr{N}{S}\myind{M}
        \mymatr{N}{V}^{T}\myind{N}
    \]
    or
    \[
    \mymatr{N}{X}\myind{M}=
    \myind{M}\mymatr{M}{U}\mymatr{N}{S}\myind{M}
    \mymatr{N}{V}^{\scriptscriptstyle T}\myind{N}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]